# highlight element on a div that covers the entire screen, z-index not works for me

Tags: css

I do not know how to make the menu icon is above the div that covers the entire screen.I am trying to generate a screen that covers all my application. 
but I want the menu circle to stand out, that the user can interact with it while the rest of the application has a div with a class called **screen** that covers 100% of my screen.

```
<div class="screen"></div>
.screen{
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  opacity:0.9;
}
```

how can I do it? (this is my wish) I need to put the icon above the div.screen

[image]

I only get this: (current problem)

[image]

I share the source code that I am doing, if you want to edit something, you must modify the **app/app.css** file(css) and **pages/home/home.html** (.html), to see in real time.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/multi-level-side-menu-waldmo?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Answer (score 0):

the ion-header part should be like this
    `<button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>`

and looks like you want to have all screen content inside .screen div so i changed it to

```
<ion-content padding>  
  <div class="screen">
    <h3>Home</h3>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

and I also change the css bit of the `screen` class to

```
.screen {
position: fixed;
background: black;
padding-top:80px;
height: 100vh;
width:100%;
top:0px;
left:0px;
opacity:0.9;
z-index: 0;
color:white;
```

}

you may want to play with `padding-top` and `color`

Comment: I need to put the icon above the div.screen

Comment: @yavg the icon is already above the div.screen, otherwise it wont repsonse when you click it, or do you have other meaning of 'above'?

Comment: @yavg is that what you try to acheive?https://stackblitz.com/edit/multi-level-side-menu-5gdnep?file=app%2Fapp.css

Answer (score 0):

1. if you can change the HTML markup, put the screen div to the bottom of ion-button,
2. add z index: 1; to '.screen' class,
3. remove the 'contain: content;' and 'overflow:hidden;' to '.toolbar' class on your CSS.

result : https://prnt.sc/kl5m7y

hope this will help :)

Comment: here is the fork: https://multi-level-side-menu-xpwc4f.stackblitz.io

1. the css: https://prnt.sc/klgozk
2. the html:

Comment: here is the fork: https://multi-level-side-menu-xpwc4f.stackblitz.io

1. the css: https://prnt.sc/klgozk
2. the html: https://prnt.sc/klgpe3